# Addition in IEEE 754

Tags: floating-point

Hi I have this simple question. When adding a positive number with a negative number, both of same exponent. Imagine that after complementing the negative we have something like this:

1.111
+
0.001
.......
This makes a Carry out.

What I want to know if I don't take care of the carry out(1) or should I(2).

If (1) The answer would be 0.000 (I think this is wrong)

If (2) The answer would be 10.000

So it helps if someone could explain what happens with the carry out in this case.

Comment: The overflow doesn't work like in signed fixpoint variables. The CPU actually remembers the carry and increases the exponent as needed (deleting the lsb in the sum of the significands)